# Partially unpack parameters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know in Python we can unpack parameters from a tuple or list:

```
def add(x,y,z):
    return x + y + z

xyz = (1,2,3)
s = add(*xyz)
```

But what is the proper way to accomplish something like this:

```
xy = (1,2)
s = add(*xy, 3)
```

> SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

I can do this:

```
s = add(*xy + (3,))
```

but that looks ugly and badly readable, and if I have a few more variables in there it would be very messy.

So, is there a cleaner way to deal with such situation?

Comment: Might not come in py3.4 - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/ but is being reviewed.

Comment: since addition is commutative, you can do `add(3,*xy)` :)

Comment: Also, `sum` is a reserved keyword, please let it be so!

Comment: This is somewhat personal preference, but I would make xy a list instead of a tuple, and append or extend it with the additional arguments prior to the *arg.

Comment: @dstromberg Yes, I thought of it, but it kind of makes it less clear what variables exactly go into the function and thus more prone to errors.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Can you please add it as an answer - it is a valuable piece of information.

Comment: @sashkello Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you name your arguments; you can then proceed as you like:

```
>>> def foo(x=None,y=None,z=None):
...     return x+y+z
...
>>> s = foo(*(1,2),z=3)
>>> s
6
```

Now if you do it like this, you can't override keyword arguments, so `foo(*(1,2), y=3)` will not work; but you can switch the order around as you like `foo(z=3, *(1,2))`.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because as long as http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132 isn't implemented, this seems to be the most appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is *much* cleaner, but since we're talking about partials..

```
from functools import partial
sum_ = partial(add,*xy)(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The pep for this has been proposed long back in 2007. You can take a look at it here - http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132

Although it might not come in py3.4 but it is certainly accepted by Guido & is proposed to come in some python 3 release.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = add(3, *xy)
```

Hope this will do.
The prototype for a method declaration in python is:

```
def method1(arg1,arg2, *args, **kwargs):
    ....your code.....
```

Comment: Good point, doesn't exactly solve a generalized situation, but interesting solution.